# HTML Geolocation does not work on mobile browser

Tags: html, geolocation

I have the following standard HTML code (from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_geolocation.asp)) which works perfectly fine on my laptop's browser but not on the mobile browser. The code is supposed to ask for permission to activate gps (in case it is turned off) then to show the GPS position of the user.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-widthm initial">
    <title>Mobile</title>
    
</head>

<body>
<h1>HTML Geolocation</h1>
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

My expectation is to get an alert requesting the user to enable GPS in case it is not enabled, otherwise show the Latitude and Longitude.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You start by saying: "it doesn't work perfectly", on the mobile browser. Underneath the code you state what you expect: "to get an alert requesting the user to enable GPS". Am I correct in assuming you didn't see a request on the mobile browser _and_ it also doesn't show the location? Knowing the exact problem you're having is quite important. It would also be helpful to know which OS is running on the mobile device and which browser you're using.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, thanks for your response. Your assumption is correct, am using Chrome on my iPhone SE which is not throwing a request to enable the GPS in case it is disabled. Also, in case GPS is enabled, the code does not return the Latitude and Longitude values.

Comment: So when the GPS is enabled, do you get the request to allow location in the browser or not? Your last comment only says "Also, in case GPS is enabled, the code does not return the Latitude and Longitude values."

Comment: @GetSet - when GPS is enabled it does not request to allow location in the browser.

Comment: Try it on a different phone. Try a different iPhone to rule out the problem being the phone itself, be that the build, some errant setting, or whatever.

Comment: OK, I think that cleared it up. I think you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77976345/edit) to clarify this issue. You don't want your question to be closed due to lack of clarity, and it is better if the readers of your question can understand the problem by only reading your question.